#  "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'addListGroup' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function"

Tags: javascript, listbox

Asked this the other day but didn't get a reply. I was to create EXACTLY THIS chained selection example (demo10):

http://www.yxscripts.com/cs/cs.zip

It all looks okay but if you open this in Google Chrome, when you select Honda from the first box - the program fails. I press 'ctrl shift J' to try and find out what the issue is and it tells me:

"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'addListGroup' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function"

Any clues as to what I can do to solve this? The error is within 'content_honda.js':

```
addListGroup("content_honda.html", "Honda");

addOption("Honda", "--- Honda vehicles ---", "");
addList("Honda", "Cars (on-the-fly)", "car", "content_honda_sub.html");
addList("Honda", "SUVs/Van", "suv", "Honda-SUVs/Van", 1);

addOption("Honda-SUVs/Van", "--- Honda SUVs/Van ---", "");
addOption("Honda-SUVs/Van", "CR-V", "CR-V");
addOption("Honda-SUVs/Van", "Pilot", "Pilot");
addOption("Honda-SUVs/Van", "Odyssey", "Odyssey", 1);

updateSubList("vehicles", "content_honda.html");
```

Comment: Wow that code is pretty old and scary looking, and chock full of global variables.  However it's impossible to tell what your problem is because you haven't posted your code.

Comment: @Pointy: the code is `demo10.html` in the linked zip file

Comment: That code works perfectly well for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function that hasn't been defined.  You're going to want to look into prerequisites for this sample (check the yxscripts.com site) or otherwise locate the necessary included scripts.  I've never seen `addListGroup` as a standard DOM function.

Comment: It isn't a standard DOM function; it's part of that (regrettable) library he's using.

Comment: But it works for Firefox and IExplorer? Sorry I don't understand too much about Javascript. You think it's down to the library i'm using?

Comment: @joe-acton - It's either a problem in the library, or you've somehow munged your Chrome installation to the point that it's not working correctly.  @Pointy says he has no problems with the code in Chrome.  You could add `alert typeof(window.addListGroup)` just before where it's called, but I'll almost guarantee it will alert "undefined".  Have you made any changes to the files?

Comment: No, i haven't changed a thing to my knowledge :/

Answer (score 0):

It's a cross-domain security issue. It is broken loading the `demo10.html` as a local file in the browser, but if you host the demos using a webserver (I used Jetty) then it works as expected.

Running as a local file I get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/so/cs/examples/demo10.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/so/cs/examples/content_honda.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

That said, I totally agree with @Pointy in that this library is pretty horrific. Personally, I would start again and build something yourself. It's a nice problem to solve and a good learning experience. You could even take advantage of some of the existing JavaScript libraries to minimise any cross-browser issues.

Comment: Ohhhh I do also get that issue, maybe its that then? I dont have the ability to test it on a webserver but ill see if I can find someone else to test it for me too. Thanks I hope thats it!     6Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/Error/examples/demo10.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/Error/examples/content_honda.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: You could download any webserver, install it and run the demo from there locally. I used [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) but there are plenty of others that would work just as well.